# why still goes inside else if?

Tags: char, scanf

I am really stuck in this problem for days now..

the program below is a part of a bigger program and which ask the user to enter a card, for ex. 2d which stands for (2 diamonds). My problem is in the function "rank" which I send to it a pointer for a string and with sscanf it will figure out which number did the user entered and which char. lets asume the user entered 2d, the program contiue going inside this (else if(suit1 != 'c' || suit1 != 'd' || suit1 != 'h' || suit1 != 's') and I really dont understand why, help plz?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rank (const char *s);

int main(){

    char text [20];

    printf("enter 2d");
    fgets(text, 4, stdin);

    rank(text);

    return 0;
}

void rank ( const char *s) {

    int num;
    char suit1;

    if((sscanf(s,"%d %c", &num , &suit1 )) == 2 ){

        if(num == 0 || num == 1){
            printf("bad rank 0 or 1");
            return 0;
        }
        else if(suit1 != 'c' || suit1 != 'd' || suit1 != 'h' || suit1 != 's'){
           printf("Bad suit1!\n");
           return 0;
        }
        else
            printf("ok");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition of your `else if` will always evaluate to `true`.

```
suit1 != 'c' || suit1 != 'd' || suit1 != 'h' || suit1 != 's'
```

#### Solution

The correct condition in your `else if` would be something like

```
!(suit1 == 'c' || suit1 == 'd' || suit1 == 'h' || suit1 == 's') // Using OR
suit1 != 'c' && suit1 != 'd' && suit1 != 'h' && suit1 != 's'    // Using AND
```

#### Breaking it down

Let's break your expression down into single conditions:

```
suit1 != 'c' // Suit1 is not 'c'
suit1 != 'd' // Suit1 is not 'd'
suit1 != 'h' // Suit1 is not 'h'
suit1 != 's' // Suit1 is not 's'
```

As you can see your code first checks if `suit1`is not `'c'`. There are two possibilities:

- `Suit1` is not `'c'` => the expression returns `true`
- `Suit1` is `'c'` => the program continues and checks if `Suit1` is `'d'`. The program only reaches this point if `Suit1` is `'c'`. Since `'c' != 'd'` the condition is `true` and your program will always execute the code in the `else if` block.

#### Rewriting the condition

You can change the expression to use `and &&` instead of `or ||` and inverting the whole thing.

```
!(suit1 == 'c' && suit1 == 'd' && suit1 == 'h' && suit1 == 's')
```

Using this syntax you can clearly see that it is simply not possible for `suit1` to have all those values at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Felix for your respons.
I wrote the code as following:

`else if (!(suit1 == 'c' && suit1 == 'd' && suit1 == 'h' && suit1 == 's'))     
                   ` 
as you said, or maybe I got your answer wrong? But it didn't worked for me.
But then i changed to the following:

`else if(suit1 != 'c' && suit1 != 'd' && suit1 != 'h' && suit1 != 's')` and it works fine now.

Comment: `!(suit1 == 'c' && suit1 == 'd' && suit1 == 'h' && suit1 == 's')` does the same as your original condition, it's just expressed with logical `&&` instead of `||`. I thought it may be clearer to understand that this can never evaluate to true. The correct condition for you to use would be one of the ones I put at the top of the answer (as you already figured out).